# How to align colons in a textview in android?

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I am trying to display strings on textview in android app
I have following strings

```
String Fruityellow = " Mango" ;
String Fruitred = " Apple" ;
String Fruitgreen = " Guava" ;
String Fruitpink = " Pomegranate" ;

So i append them and print them on textview
output_display = "Fruityellow     :" + Fruityellow + "\r\n" + 
         "Fruitred        :" + Fruitred + "\r\n" +
         "Fruitgreen      :" + Fruitgreen + "\r\n" +
         "Fruitpink       :" + Fruitpink + "\r\n" );

text_view.settext(output);
```

But the display shows vertically **misaligned** colons .Why ?

So i used spannable string to keep colons at center

```
SpannableString span_colon      = new SpannableString(":");
span_colon.setSpan((new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER)), 0, span_colon.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

spanned total_display = (Spanned)TextUtils.concat("Fruityellow",span_colon,Fruityellow,
"\r\nFruitred",span_colon,Fruitred,
"\r\nFruitgreen",span_color,Fruitgreen,
"\r\nFruitpink",span_color,Fruitpink);

 text_view.settext(total_display );
```

**Current ouptut is:**

```
Fruityellow:Mango
Fruitred:Apple
Fruitgreen:guava
Fruitpink:Pomegranate
```

**Expected output is :**

```
Fruityellow     : Mango
Fruitred        : Apple
Fruitgreen      : guava
Fruitpink       : Pomegranate
```

if i just print span_colon it correctly comes in center of screen

How to get colon in center of screen in textview ?
colon is not needed to be in center but should be vertically aligned .

Comment: Can u add an image of current and expected output ?

Comment: @ADM added expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way to use space is not working because the font used for the TextView has different width and size for each character, including space itself. If you can add `android:fontFamily="monospace"` to the xml, then it will show space as you expected, but maybe it's not the font you are expecting for your TextView.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved using only one `TextView` since the texts size may vary independently. You may need an additional `TextView` wrapped inside a `ConstraintLayout` or `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` with necessary constraints applied.

> The trick *(but may be a worst trick)* is to append the colon as a
> prefix to the fruit name instead of as a suffix to the fruit label.

You can use `SpannableStringBuilder` to achieve this.

```
val label  = SpannableStringBuilder()
label.append("\nFruit Yellow ")
label.append("\nFruit Red ")
label.append("\nFruit Green ")

val des = SpannableStringBuilder()
des.append(": Mango\n")
des.append(": Apple\n")
des.append(": Guava\n")

binder.msgViewLabel.text = label.toString()
binder.msgViewDes.text = des.toString()
```

XML part - UI

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id = "@+id/container_layout"
   android:layout_width = "match_parent"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
   android:orientation = "horizontal"
   android:weightSum = "1">

  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
     android:id = "@+id/msg_view_label"
     android:layout_width = "0dp"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight = "0.5"
     android:textColor = "@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
     android:id = "@+id/msg_view_des"
     android:layout_width = "0dp"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight = "0.5"
     android:textColor = "@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Output

[image]

**NOTE :** You can adjust the `layout_weight` property to set the space needed for `label` and `description`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be like that (just have one), it certainly doesn't make sense in a
Text View because you're going to customize him.
In general, there are 3 logical modes for this method, each of which you can build according to your choice.

- Reformat your text to avoid tables
- Use WebView to render your HTML table
- Use native widgets and containers (e.g., TableLayout) for your table